# UISCrollview with paging enabled

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, paging

I want a UIScrollview with both paging and zooming at the same time. So i used  2 UIScrollviews. MainScrollview with paging enabled and the subscrollview with paging disabled. So i can do zooming and panning in the subscrollview and paging from main scrollview.
Now the problem is how can i know that the user have moved into next page. None of the delegates are invoking. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you want to scroll and paging it's necessary to add on subscrollview photo which is on page. For this add a button zoom and zoom disable for paging.